# Template to parse json.loads message

Tags: python, json

I have so much similar codes in my script

```
      sinkId = json_string_into_dict["wirepas"]["packetReceivedEvent"]["header"]["sinkId"]
      eventId = json_string_into_dict["wirepas"]["packetReceivedEvent"]["header"]["eventId"]
      sourceAddress = json_string_into_dict["wirepas"]["packetReceivedEvent"]["sourceAddress"]
      destinationAddress = json_string_into_dict["wirepas"]["packetReceivedEvent"]["destinationAddress"]
      sourceEndpoint = json_string_into_dict["wirepas"]["packetReceivedEvent"]["sourceEndpoint"]
```

How can I define template to void duplicate part of code?

I want to do it something like it

```
PARSING_TEMPLATE = json_string_into_dict["wirepas"]["packetReceivedEvent"]["header"]
PARSING_TEMPLATE + ["sinkId"]
PARSING_TEMPLATE + ["eventId"]
PARSING_TEMPLATE + ["sourceAddress"]
PARSING_TEMPLATE + ["destinationAddress"]
PARSING_TEMPLATE + ["sourceEndpoint"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might as well just reference down to the `"packetReceivedEvent"` key:

```py
packetReceivedEvent = json_string_into_dict["wirepas"]["packetReceivedEvent"]
sinkId = packetReceivedEvent["header"]["sinkId"]
eventId = packetReceivedEvent["header"]["eventId"]
sourceAddress = packetReceivedEvent["sourceAddress"]
destinationAddress = packetReceivedEvent["destinationAddress"]
sourceEndpoint = packetReceivedEvent["sourceEndpoint"]
```